# Bangla Text extraction from image[ it may contain bengali and english language]

Tags: java, python, android, ocr, text-recognition

I have a visiting card contains Name and Adress. those are written in two different languages ( Bengali and English). Now I want to extract the recognized text from the captured image of the visiting card using android or javascript whatever.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I've used 'Puthi' previously to decode bengali text(not used professionally, but in a hackathon). 
Link:
https://github.com/afrida67/Puthi-OCR-REST-API</s>

For english I only know about Tesseract https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

Hope this helps. :)

All the above libraries are obsolete now,

I think Firebase Ml kit might do the job if you're ok with the limit :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text?authuser=0#before-you-begin

Comment: thank you @mohaimanul . Probably puthi API is obsoleted. Can you help to use Tesseract in Javascript or android?

Comment: sorry my bad, I checked further and found out both of these libraries are obsolete now.

I think Firebase Ml kit might do the job if you're ok with the limit :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text?authuser=0#before-you-begin

Comment: But Firebase ML kit does not support the Bengali Language.

Comment: this documentation says it does
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/langid-support

But I haven't used it myself so I may be wrong.